# Snowflake Query Performance Improvement

Tags: sql, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just started working with the Snowflake database.

Snowflake does not allow for Indexes to be created, that being said, what are some ways I can speed up my SQL query performance?

In the past, I would create #temp tables and throw some indexes on, but this is not possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why someone voted to close, please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating temp tables, materialized views are common approaches to improve queries. If you want to improve the performance of point lookup queries, please check SOS:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/search-optimization-service.html

If you want to improve data warehouse style queries, check clustering keys and auto-clustering:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html

I also recommend you to check the following post:

https://dzone.com/articles/snowflake-performance-tuning-top-5-best-practices